# Set Div value before document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to set Div value dynamically before document ready.

I have a div in my test page. I want to set the Div value dynamically before jquery document ready. Which event i can use.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: can you tell me what is your requirement , why do you want to set so early and not in css

Answer (score 2):

you can give it as inline code

it doesn't wait till the page load's , it will load as soon as it reaches that code.

```
<script language="javascript">

execute your code here

</script >
```

The only thing with this code is , the html you are trying to manipulate should be available by that time.

Answer (score 2):

Put this script at the bottom of your document (before `</body>` tag):

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    var yourDiv = document.getElementById('yourDivId');
    yourDiv.innerText = 'something set into div now'; // If you want to set pure text;
    yourDiv.innerHtml = '<p>To set HTML inside an element</p>';
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pavan- How can you set the value before element get created on page...Document.ready method set the value once the element get created I dont understand what you are trying to do but according to me if there is no element in dom how you can set the text in it.

You can try out `OnLoad()` event of the `body` element may do your task.

**EDIT**

Try this : not much sure about this

```
function test () {     
       alert(this.readyState);  
}  

<div onreadystatechange="test();"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery's document ready is tied to the DOMContentLoaded event. You really can't reliably manipulate the DOM before that event is fired.

Comment: Yeah you can. As long as the part you are manipulating is complete.

Comment: yes, but there is no reliable way to know when that part is complete

Comment: Inline script after the close of that element (and its parent if you are indirectly affecting it, too). Or just at the bottom of the page, after anything else (including script elements that could possibly contain document.write, not that they should :))

Answer (score 0):

```
<div><script type="text/javascript">document.write('content')</script></div>
```

You'll read sometimes that document.write should be avoided but this case would be an exception.

Answer (score 0):

document ready is what you want since it starts when the DOM is ready, but before all the HTML elements like such as div is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Use

> document.getElementById("successAndErrorMessages").innerHTML="someContent";